# How to make my navbar always on top?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have made a website using the HTML5 Template called "Photon" and I've added a Bootstrap navbar from another template.

My problem is that when I scroll the page, pictures get on top of my navbar and I don't want that. However text goes under the navbar just like I want it to.

I've already set the navbar's opacity to 100 and its CSS position is fixed.

I've made a few screenshots ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEPKq.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYq9t.png)) so that you can see exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: It's a [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) issue, but without any actual code to reference that's about as much help as we'll be able to provide.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Set `z-index: 100` on your navbar, obviously it doesn't need to be a 100, but I can't see what your code looks like, so 100 is a safe bet

Comment: Not great advice given you don't know what OP's stacking context looks like.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it.
My code is reaaally really long so I didn't want to post it here.

Comment: Wow, it actually worked ! Thank you so much, this was very important to me.

Comment: It's ok, glad I can help.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply fix position to your nav class.

```
.navClass{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
}
```

Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @SamirChahine: top: 0px; is also needed.